# Post list of dynamic objects back to Spring controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, post

I have a class called 'User' (with fields userName and userAge) and a wrapper class which holds the list of User objects. I added this wrapper class to my model and send it to view.

I iterated the list and able to display the data in View. My query is I have an option in view to add new user, is it possible to add a new user object to the existing list in view and post it back to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean ?

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User create(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
        logger.info("creating user " );
        return yourList.save(user);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please correct me if my understanding is correct, Every time a new user is created in client side, there should be an ajax call to send the object to controller to add it to existing list. How it will reflect in view?

Comment: Please read this book : Spring MVC Beginner’s Guide by Amuthan G (Author). You 'll learn how to send ajax requests using angular js